# input tag value attribute not showing data with in the double quotes

Tags: jsp

event.eventName value in dataBase=Holiday "Independence Day" event

while editing the form it shows the value as Holiday event.(double quotes value is not showing).
How can I display Exact value?

Comment: Post your relevent Java and jsp code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed Using escapeXml="true" in Jstl tag.